# Animate view width with Google Databinding

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-databinding

**I would like to animate a view width when the value of a boolean in my ViewModel changes... But I have no idea how to bind this.**

I have this view:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/help_search_et"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/border_search_help_txt"
     android:hint="@string/hint_how_can_we_help"
     android:singleLine="true" />
```

And a view model:

```
public class SomethingViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
     private boolean isSearchEnabled;

     void handleSearchRequest(){
        if(isSearchEnabled) {
            isSearchEnabled = false;

            /* I need to make the EditText expand */

        } else {
            isSearchEnabled = true;

            /* I need to make the EditText colapse */
        }
    }

}
```

As I am using the MVVM, I cannot have a reference of the View... so I cannot trigger an animation in the view, I need the Databinding to do that for me... But I don't know how to trigger this animation in my view.

**I don't need help with width animation, just the data binding part.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The first that comes to mind is to use Transitions:

```
binding.addOnRebindCallback(new OnRebindCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreBind(ViewDataBinding binding) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(
                (ViewGroup)binding.getRoot());
        return super.onPreBind(binding);
    }
});
```

Another alternative is to create a BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("isExpanded")
public void setExpanded(View view, boolean isExpanded) {
    // expand or collapse View, depending on isExpanded
}
```

And you'd have to bind it in your layout:

```
<View app:isExpanded="@{viewModel.isSearchEnabled}" .../>
```